# Start Instances of Java Program, Each on a Separate Core

Tags: java

I have a Java program that I start like this on Windows Server 2008.

```
java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre\lib\ext\*" -server -Xms128m -Xmx512m    something.something.Main config.xml
```

It's long running, and I want to be able to start two or more instances, and I'm wondering if there's a way to specify the CPU/Core to get better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to attach instances of Java programs to specific CPUs / cores. As an alternative, consider making the program concurrent, i.e. start multiple executor threads internally. This way you need to run only a single instance of it, but its individual threads would run on distinct processors/cores if there are multiple available ones.

This in fact probably yields better performance and is more scalable than running multiple processes - the [`Executor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) framework allows you to choose different thread pools, change the number of threads even dynamically, manages dead threads for you etc.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to start a new virtual machine to get better performance, you can use multi-threading to use all available cores within the same process. In fact that will perform much better that two different processes.

But if you want to start two different process, just do it; the Operating System will do the rest for you.

Check this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html) for more information about Java processes and threads.

Comment: What are the memory usage implications of starting, say, two instances as opposed to two threads in one instance? I imagine I'd have two JVMs running, and nearly double the memory consumption?

Comment: Threads are much lighter objects than processes (in Operating System terms), and apart from that, you are launching two virtual machines, that have a rather big memory footprint and starting time.

Comment: You just double the min (-Xms128m) memory consumption. The real memory you use depends of the algorithms under.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should not be worried about that - your OS does the distribution of the running processes to the available cores/processors.